# Do Augments override the base item's stats?

Tags: diablo-iii

I understand how the cube works to do the augmentation, but does it stack with the item's stat, or override it completely?

Edit: Because people seem to not understand, but was answered in comments..
I am not asking if the secondary rolls of augment stack, I am/was asking if it stacked with the underlying base stat of the item. The answer posted in comments is that it will stack under it's own name of the gem it was leveled with. For example (now that I moved forward and can give real example)..

Burden of the Invoker before:
[607 Strength]
[Other Stuff]

Burden of the Invoker after:
[607 Strength]
[305 Strength "Gem Name"] <- another stat
[Other Stuff]

Granted multipliers below are off, overall the focal point of question answered.
End Edit

For example:
- Armor Item with base stat of +600S

Add Augment Legendary lvl 50, Rubies = 750S

Would the resulting stats be +750S or 1350S?

So if you have a high roll already (say alter above hypothetical to 650) but has no vitality, would it be more worthwhile to not augment your base stat then?

Comment: no. im not asking how it works, that is how i knew what the numbers would be. it talks about secondary augmentations (so first time rubies, second time diamonds) the subsequent augmentations would override. nowhere does it mention if it stacks with the base stat of the item, or overrides that stat.

Comment: The first augment ADDS, the second augment overrides previous augment.

Comment: It does not override the stat. It is a separately named stat with the added benefits listed in their own row.

Comment: omg thank you for understanding what I was asking. So (and this is why I'm trying to figure out) if I have +738 Str on my shoulders, and I roll htree rubies, it will have that +738 and a separate +750 (easy numbers*) for an overall of +1488 Str for the entire peice yes? idk how but if your able to get this unflagged, and post answer, it seems you are giving me the exact answer I couldn't find (and save others heartache*)

Comment: @alykins yes that is how it works.